# Fabric NDK C++ header location

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, google-fabric

I'm trying to find the location of fabric header files for the NDK. I've set up the maven repositories as per the instructions on the fabric site and I imagine this ought to download the headers, but this isn't clear and if they have, I have no idea where they've put them. Attempting to build my project with

```
#include <Crashlytics/Crashlytics.h>
```

fails. I can get fabric to work in the java files but I'd like to have access within my C++ code as well.